# Show popup or tooltip on the map by default, without any interaction( mouse hover, click) in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, label

I know there is a way to show properties by mouse hove and click event on the map, but my question is how can I show the properties without mouse hover or click event.

I tried using label pane but it's not working in my case.

```
// show map
mymap = L.map('map_canvas');

// For Label
mymap.createPane('labels');
// This pane is above markers but below popups
mymap.getPane('labels').style.zIndex = 650;
// Layers in this pane are non-interactive and do not obscure mouse/touch events
mymap.getPane('labels').style.pointerEvents = 'none';

var positronLabels = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '©OpenStreetMap, ©CartoDB',
        pane: 'labels'
}).addTo(mymap);


layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.block_name + '</br>' + feature.properties.DIST_NAME,{
            noHide: true,
            direction: 'auto'
        });
```

But still, it's not showing by default but it showing when I click on the map.

Please give me some suggestions on how to do it, I already wasted more than 10 days on this single work.

Happy coding.

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#layer-openpopup

Comment: @IvanSanchez still same issue

Comment: [Works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/a4qcXeWnx8wnY5q3). Remember the thing about [reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: it's for a marker. I don't want a marker even. I just want to show the value over the map that's all. like the way it shows https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/color-axis

Comment: Then please edit your question and rephrase to include that information.